# Python nested list conditional delete

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list of lists where some lists are not complete. I.e.:

```
data = [
['id1',1],
['id2'],
['id3'],
['id4'],
['id5',1]
]
```

I want to create a new list that contains only "full" lists.

Desired output:

```
[
['id1',1],
['id5',1]
]
```

I have tried:

```
new_data = [i for i in data if i[1]]
```

However, this returned:

> List index error: Index out of range

I find it odd because the `if[1]` is right there.

### Question

Is there a simple fix for a one-line approach, or must we use a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying accessing the values, check for length:

```
new_data = [i for i in data if len(i) == 2]
```